# Is it possible to concat inside [(ngModel)] angular

Tags: angular

i have two text-areas and each one of them is for one property of my object ( aboutMe and whatIDo )
and the display of the text-areas depends on the sub-menu that i clicked on , so each one of the text-areas is on a different sub-menu , so i was trying to keep a track on each of the text-areas values when i change of view but didn't find a way to do such thing but i had an idea of using the [(ngModel)] directive but i didn't know how to concat inside ngModel

this is my object :

```js
    newExperience: Experience = ({
    id: "",
    mainTheme: "",
    optionalTheme: "",
    mainLanguage: "",
    optionalLanguages: [],
    audience: [],
    location: "",
    aboutMe: "",
    whatIDo: "",
    });
```

and what i want to do it something like this :

```html
   <textarea id="about_host_input" class="_1hfdk52"
   [maxLength]=(section.textLength) 
   name= {{section.inputName}}
   placeholder={{section.placeHolder}}
   [(ngModel)]="newExperience.'+'section.inputName"
   (input)="handleTextAreaChange($event,textArea.name)"#textArea></textarea>
```

i was trying to concat the name of the input and the name of the object so i will correspond to a
property because the section.inputName is equal to a name of that object properties
`(section.inputName = aboutMe  for expl )` so if the concatenation is correct it
will be something like this `[(ngModel)]="newExperience.aboutMe"`  and it should work as i want but the concatenation in the ngModel directive is wrong didn't know how to do such thing

Comment: Try with `[ngModel]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan i will do but i didn't know how to concat inside it

Comment: It would be: `[ngModel]="newExperience[section.inputName]"`. That should also work with `[(ngModel)]` if you need two-way binding (I had misread the question).

Comment: @ConnorsFan i totally forgot that i can access an object property that way i thought about it but i thought i was wrong didn't try it am so dumb ! thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using concatenation try using it as property name

```js
<textarea id="about_host_input" class="_1hfdk52"
   [maxLength]=(section.textLength) 
   name= {{section.inputName}}
   placeholder={{section.placeHolder}}
   [ngModel]="newExperience[section.inputName]"
   (input)="handleTextAreaChange($event,textArea.name)"#textArea></textarea>
```

Comment: yes ! that's what i did , i totally forgot about it , but still thanks for your help i appreciate that !